# Working with date-time format, cant handle POSIXct. (Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied)

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a date-time column in my database in a format of "2017-01-02 8:27" as example. I want to add 10 minutes to this date-time version.

```
dat$EventTime=as.POSIXct(strptime( dat$EventTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz = "", origin = '1970-01-01 00:00')
```

--date-time format becomes 2017-01-02 08:27:00 which is ok, however when I try to add 10 minutes

```
dat$EventTime[1]+minute(10)
```

--I come across with this error

> Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied

--Could you please help me with that issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  I don't get any such message from `library(lubridate); as.POSIXct(strptime("2017-01-02 8:27", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), tz = "", origin = '1970-01-01 00:00') + minutes(10)`
 Note that the works without any packages.  `as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 8:27", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + 10 * 60`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `anytime()` from the [`anytime`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package which does this *without requiring format or origin*:

```
R> anytime("2017-01-02 08:27")
[1] "2017-01-02 08:27:00 CST"
R>
```

The resulting object is of course `POSIXct` so can calculate at at will:

```
R> anytime("2017-01-02 08:27") + seq(1,6)*60
[1] "2017-01-02 08:28:00 CST" "2017-01-02 08:29:00 CST" "2017-01-02 08:30:00 CST"
[4] "2017-01-02 08:31:00 CST" "2017-01-02 08:32:00 CST" "2017-01-02 08:33:00 CST"
R>
```

*Edit:* And I just realized that we used a single digit '8' which the default (Boost) parser does not like.  Correcting to '08' now.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do

```
as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 8:27", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC") + 10 * 60
#[1] "2017-01-02 08:37:00 UTC"
```

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hm("2017-01-02 8:27") + minutes(10)
```

To do this for entire column replace string with column name

```
as.POSIXct(dat$EventTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC") + 10 * 60
```